# Dynamic where in a Sql Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

i would like to create a sql query like these :

```
Select* from Table where 
(if picod=1)
{
  dvdt= "xxxx" 
}
(if picod=2)
{
  cddt= "xxxx" 
}
(if picod=3)
{
  bldt= "xxxx" 
}
(if picod=3)
{
  fadt= "xxxx" 
}
```

I don't know how doing this in SQL .

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You have two of the same conditions?

Comment: What is your table structure?

Comment: LukeHennerley, it's a type ;)

Comment: The SQL CASE statement (in your version of SQL) will also help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select* from Table 
where (picod=1 and dvdt= 'xxxx') or  (picod=2 and cddt= 'xxxx') or ....... (XXXX) or....
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `OR`

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Table
WHERE   (Picod = 1 AND dvdt = 'xxxx')
OR      (Picod = 2 AND cddt = 'xxxx')
OR      (Picod = 3 AND bldt = 'xxxx')
OR      (Picod = 3 AND fadt = 'xxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT  *
    FROM    Table
    WHERE  'xxxx' = case Picod  
     when 1 then dvdt
     when 2 then cddt
     when 3 then bldt 
     when 4 then fadt 
    end
```